# Why nesting in css class selector don't work as expected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this paragraph element:

```
<p class='big bold'>Some random text</p>
```

And try to style it like this

```
p .big{
    font-size:60px;
}
p .bold{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

It doesn't work, but when I remove the p selector it work .

I thought It will work because In sass nesting work like that, if not there is no such a benefit of using nesting in sass .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p .bold
```

Spaces in CSS selectors denote descendent generations, so the above selector is looking for a descendent element of `p` that has the class `.bold`

You need

```
p.bold
```

Comment: I think a more accurate term is descendant, child implies immediate child, in my head, at least.

Comment: @JuanMendes Agreed. However child implies immediate descendant in my head.

Comment: Yes, I should have said descendent. Of course, the child selector is `>`

Comment: Well, actually `>` is called *[child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)* :-)

Comment: Selector, combinator, either way it matches child elements, a particular subset of descendant elements.

Answer (score 2):

remove space as space is used for `descendents`, you need to select `<p> with class bold` not `class bold within paragraph tag`

```
p.bold{
     font-weight:bold;
 }
```

same goes for `p.big`

Answer (score 0):

It must be `p.big` and `p.bold` or `p.big.bold`, otherwise won't work,
Hope it helps mate :)